# Удаление прозрачности у изображений

Tags: php, gd

Есть несколько картинок товара с разного цвета, все картинки имеют прозрачность, которую я пытаюсь удалить, с помощью библиотеки gd, отключая alpha-канал с белым фоном. Если цвет товара черный, то вокруг него образуется серая область. С остальными цветами проблем не  возникает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Imagick пробовали?

Comment: @ilyaplot да, с ним области нет, но цвет товара становится серый http://joxi.ru/Vm6a9aoHNk8VrZ

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот такой способ с Imagick.

```
$Imagick = new Imagick();
$Imagick->readImage('file.png');
$Imagick->setImageBackgroundColor('white'); //задаем фон
$Imagick = $Imagick->flattenImages(); // склеиваем слои
$Imagick->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$Imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(80);
$Imagick->writeImage('file.jpg');       
$Imagick->destroy();
```

Comment: Именно так делаю, результат серый, как на скрине в комментарии выше. Но, серый даже просто при открытии и сохранении в Imagick, без удаления прозрачности.